# Code porting from IAR ver 7.50 to IAR ver 6.30

Tags: arm, stm32, iar

I'm using IAR 7.50 code limit version. Now i'm trying to port my project to IAR ver 6.30. 
Please anyone share the procedure to follow to do this porting.

Thank you in Advance
Basavanagouda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will lose all your setting when going back versions. So take a copy of the project first. Keep one copy open in 7.50 and then you can either open the project files with 6.30 and copy all the setting from 7.50 to 6.30, or probably better to create a new project in 6.30 and copy all the setting and add all the files etc.
There is no easy way to go backwards as you always lose setting. Going forwards is fine.